# How can I filter in 2 tables in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to search in the tables by the `Contract_Num` which is in other table but there are relationship between them.

```
<b>Search By:</b>
@Html.TextBox("contracts.Contract_Num") <text>Contract Number</text>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />


                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.Contract_Num)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monthe)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Receipt)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @{
                    var Balance = item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.Receipt;
                                }

                                @Balance
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Not)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("تعديل", "Edit", new { id = item.ContractMonth_Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("التفاصيل", "Details", new { id = item.ContractMonth_Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", new { id = item.ContractMonth_Id })
                            </td>

                    </tbody>
                }

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

}

This is the controller :

```
//GET: ContractMonth
public ActionResult Index(string Contract_Num)
{
    return View(_context.ContractMonth
                        .Where(x => x.contracts.Contract_Num).ToString());
}
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly Convert 'int' to 'bool'

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the filter value, and use Single instead of Where:

```
var cm = _context.ContractMonth.Single(x => x.contracts.Contract_Num == Contract_Num);
var cn = cm.Contract_Num;

return View(cm.ToString());
```

Comment: operator '==' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int' and string this error come

Comment: you can change the `Index(string Contract_Num)` to `Index(int Contract_Num)`

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Contract_Num' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'RES.Controllers.ContractMonthController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Use `Index(int? Contract_Num)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include filter and int to string conversion. Use below code its helpful for you

var contractMonth= _context.ContractMonth.FirstOrDefault(x => 
x.contracts.Contract_Num.ToString() == Contract_Num);

var contactNumber= cm.Contract_Num;

return View(contactNumber.ToString());

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 43:             var contactNumber = contractMonth.contracts.Contract_Num;

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast both variable in one datatype so you can compare.

```
List<ContractMonth> contractMonth = new List<ContractMonth>();
contractMonth =_context.ContractMonth.Where(x =>( x.contracts.Contract_Num==null?"":contracts.Contract_Num.ToString()) == Contract_Num.ToString()).ToList();
     return View(contractMonth);
```

Comment: this error come when i run application : Sequence contains no elements

Comment: i can do that in j Query ? maybe it is beater

Comment: can you please share what is ContractMonth?
whar you store in ContractMonth,schema of ContractMonth etc

Comment: you can do Jquery search,it will be better if you load all the stuff in one shot

Comment: How i can do that can help me?

Comment: please share view page or table structure so i can give you better idea

Comment: you can get idea from here 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

Comment: Error 2 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RES.Models.ContractMonth>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrdefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrdefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RES.Models.ContractMonth>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Zahra\Desktop\RES\RES\Controllers\ContractMonthController.cs 50 123 RES

Comment: i have update answer, you can use Datatable.js
please take a look on it https://datatables.net/

Comment: sorry there are error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Contract_Num' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'RES.Controllers.ContractMonthController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: this error come because in database there is null value i have update code please check

Comment: you writ nux it is mean nul?

Comment: Error 2 The name 'contracts' does not exist in the current context this error coming in the second contract

Comment: can you update question with all info, model view and controller, without proper question we are also helpless

Comment: can we go the chat and i will send the all code there because i can enter all code her

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190953/discussion-between-rajdip-khavad-and-software-developer).

Answer (score 0):

I was certain that the problem occurred in this line:

```
return View(_context.ContractMonth.Where(x => x.contracts.Contract_Num).ToString())
```

Here are several problems I found:

1) LINQ `Where()` extension method requires boolean expression with equality operator against action method's parameter, not just use `Contract_Num` directly.

2) `ToString()` on the end of `Where()` in LINQ to Entities will return fully qualified name of the `IQueryable` instance instead of selected `Contract_Num`s. Use `ToList()` to return `List` collection instead.

Therefore, based from your controller and view and assuming `Contract_Num` is an `int`, you should return a list from action method like this example below:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Contract_Num)
{
    if (Contract_Num != null)
    {
        var list = _context.ContractMonth.Where(x => x.contracts.Contract_Num == Contract_Num.Value).ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
    else
    {
        // return new empty list 
    }
}
```

If you have foreign key relationship between `Contracts` and `ContractMonth`, I suggest you to use `join` syntax or `Join` extension method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Contract_Num)
{
    if (Contract_Num != null)
    {
        var list = (from cm in _context.ContractMonth
                    join ct in _context.Contracts
                    on cm.Contract_Num equals ct.Contract_Num
                    where cm.Contract_Num == Contract_Num.Value
                    select cm).ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
    else
    {
        // return new empty list 
    }
}
```

Additionally, to prevent both null value and empty list entering `foreach` loop you should put an if-condition before iterating the list:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        // DisplayFor and other stuff
    }
}
```

**Note:** You need to avoid unnecessary type casts inside LINQ to Entities query as possible because some casting methods like `ToString()` is not convertible to SQL statement.